# Can an app use both alerts and banners in Notification Center?

Tags: macos, cocoa, nsusernotification

I am creating a Mac OS X application to use Notification Center. Some notifications should remain on the screen until the user interacts with them, and others should disappear shortly after displaying.

The `NSUserNotificationAlertStyle` key and changing System Preferences allow changing between banners and alerts. However, both approaches change all the notifications sent from my application.

Can I send some notifications as alerts and others as banners? If so, how?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`NSUSerNotificationAlertStyle` is the only way the developer can set the *default* notification style for the application, and it sets the style for **all** notifications from that app.

If you think it's really important for you to have 2 different kinds of notifications you can work around the problem by having a hidden helper application with a different NSUserNotificationAlertStyle than the main app.

Remember though you set the **default** notification style, but the user can change it whenever he wants in the notification center prefs, making your helper app useless.

Answer (score 1):

No. The different notification types exist so that the user may select what he/she prefers, not so that the developer can.

If you feel your app should have this ability, you should file an enhancement request at http://bugreporter.apple.com and let Apple know.