# How to prevent a delivered NSUserNotification Popup from removing a previous Notification Popup

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, notifications, popup

I'm trying to get 2 notifications to pop up at once, stacked on top of eachother, but when I deliver the second notification, it pushes the first popup out of the display.

```
     NSUserNotification *notification = [[NSUserNotification alloc] init];
     notification.title = @"1";
     notification.informativeText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"First Popup"];
     notification.soundName = NSUserNotificationDefaultSoundName;
     [[NSUserNotificationCenter defaultUserNotificationCenter] deliverNotification:notification];

     NSUserNotification *notification2 = [[NSUserNotification alloc] init];
     notification2.title = @"2";
     notification2.informativeText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Second Popup"];
     notification2.soundName = NSUserNotificationDefaultSoundName;
     [[NSUserNotificationCenter defaultUserNotificationCenter] deliverNotification:notification2];
```

Is there a flag or something I could set to stop the second popup from removing the first one from my display?  (They both still exist in the notification center)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to enable notifications to show as `Alerts` in the `Notifications` in `System Preference`.

[image: popup with close button]

and then you can remove/dismiss the notifications as/if you want using:

`- (void)removeDeliveredNotification:(NSUserNotification *)notification;`

You can use Growl also for the purpose but i don't know if that will show notifications in notification center.
I don't know any other way of doing this and will love to learn that.

[image: Notification Center]

Comment: ah, so you don't think i can programmatically force the notifications to be alerts for the user?

Comment: you can do that. just look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12320051/can-an-app-use-both-alerts-and-banners-in-notification-center

Comment: i hope the link helps, but again the user will have the power to change style from `System Preferences`.